# SessionStorage seems to remain empty

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML5/Javascript and am having a conceptual issue I think. I'm using Aptana as my environment and it is using FireFox for the browser to debug.

Here's the code in question:

```
var req = new ContactRequest("Mister Peachy", "peach.png", "One Liner Message" );

sessionStorage.Requests = new Array();
sessionStorage.Requests[0] = req;

req = new ContactRequest("Anon Ymous", "person.png", "Another one line msg");

sessionStorage.Requests[1] = req;
```

The issue seems to be that sessionStorage.Requests always equals "" . I tried using .setItem but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is stringify your data to store and parse it to retrieve. Here's a little interface that I have written

```
App.session = (function () {
  var self = {};

  self.get = function (key) {
    var b = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
    return b ? JSON.parse(b) : null;
  }

  self.set = function (key, value) {
    var b = JSON.stringify(value);
    sessionStorage.setItem(key, b);
  }

  return self;
})();

var session = App.session;
session.set('foo', 'bar');
var bar = session.get('foo');
console.log(bar);
```

Comment: Also note that JSON is not suppported in all browsers by default, but you can use JSON2 (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) when it is not built in by default.

Comment: @Matt: are you aware of any browsers that support sessionStorage but not JSON?

Answer (score 1):

`sessionStorage` cannot store objects, it can only store strings.

If you want to store anything else, you'll have to use JSON.

Comment: @Driss Zouak: That is correct. `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` share the exact same API

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#storage-0),

> Each Storage object provides access to a list of key/value pairs,
>   which are sometimes called items. Keys are strings. Any string
>   (including the empty string) is a valid key. *Values are similarly
>   strings.*

Emphasis added.  You can't store objects in sessionStorage.

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage) also has comments on this:

> Note: Although the values can be set and read via the standard
>   JavaScript property access method usage of getItem and setItem methods
>   is recommended.
>
> Note: Keep in mind that everything you store in any of the storages
>   described in this page is converted to string via its .toString method
>   before stored. So trying to store a common object will result in
>   string "[object Object]" to be stored instead of the object or its
>   JSON representation. Using native JSON parsing and serialization
>   methods provided by the browser is a good and common way for storing
>   objects in string format.